# Bounced Subscribers, do they translate into Opted Out of Emails in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, bounce-management

Hard bounces in Marketing Cloud automatically set Held status in All Subscribers, if we have Marketing Cloud Connector setup, how does this translate into Sales/Service Cloud? Will they appear as opted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not automatically show up in Sales/Service Cloud as opted out if the subscribers have a Held status.

You will need to create a process to update in Sales/Service Cloud.

1. Query [_Subscribers Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) with a status of Unsubscribed or Held. The subscriber key should be your Contact Id, Lead Id, or PersonContactId if using PersonAccounts
2. Inject into a one-step journey to update the Contact or Lead
3. Or use a SSJS script to update Sales/Service Cloud